# How do I logout of Hangout on Android 4.4?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-hangouts

Hangout is the default messaging app in Android 4.4. I know that it's possible to use a third party application for SMS, but it there a way to log out of hangout entirely? Or at least to block the notifications? I keep receiving chat notification both on my phone and my computer and it's really annoying.

I do not want to uninstall/deactivate it because I still want to be able to use it while I'm on the road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3118600?hl=en

this doesn't work? I haven't tried it, because I don't have hangouts on my phone.

**EDIT 1**

*Sign out of Hangouts*

*TIP: If you don’t want to receive notifications, enable Snooze notifications.*

Touch Menu  >​ Settings > Touch your Google account > scroll to the bottom and touch Sign out.

Comment: So simple that I'm seriously ashamed that I didn't find that on my own... Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies.